# how to call controller function from run block in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie for angularjs. I want to call controller function from run block.

**Somethings like:-**

```
//index.html
  .
  .
  <li class="nav-sap"><a ng-click="loadSfData(5)" href="">Sf</a></li>
  .
  .


//app.js   

myApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

   $rootScope.callFunctionFromGlobally=function(sid){

     //Here, i want call controller function
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML

```
<div id="yourcontainer" ng-app="" ng-controller="mainController">
</div>
```

And inside your `run` you can call the `controller` function like below

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('yourcontainer')).scope();
scope.yourControllerMethod();
```